# How can I tell the "windows security center" that I'm an "antivirus"?

Tags: windows-xp, antivirus, antivirus-integration

we are developing an anti-virus, I'm trying to find out how can we tell the operating system -windows XP in this case- that our software is an anti-virus. I want that the OS recognize our software as an anti-virus and the security center list it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have to sign an NDA to get the information. Quoth [MSDN forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/windowscompatibility/thread/e1dd7668-0465-4200-a4bc-c38d091396ae):

> To register an antivirus product:
>
> Must be a member of the Microsoft
>   Virus Initiative.
>
> OR
>
> Must meet the following three
>   requirements:
>
> 1. Must have a standard NDA with Microsoft.
> 2. Must be a member of AVPD or a member of EICAR or must sign and
>      adhere to a code of ethics relating to
>      malware research and malware handling.
> 3. Must meet independent testing requirements:
>
>    a. If you are using your own antimalware engine, you must pass
>      VB100 and meet at least one of the
>      following:
>
>    - ICSA Labs - Pass
>    - West Coast Labs - Pass
>    - AV-Test.de – 90% or higher
>    - AV-Comparitives – 90% or higher
>
>    b. If you are packaging an antimalware engine from another
>      company:
>
>    - The company who developed the engine must meet the
>        above requirements.

Comment: There is, but they won't tell you how until you go through the hoops, for obvious reasons.

Answer (score 1):

In order to be able to register an AV product with Windows Security Center, you need a private API from Microsoft or, starting with Windows 10 build 1809 you need to register a Protected Service. In order to do both these things, you need to be member in the MVI.

Just for the record, a few years later now, the requirements have changed a bit.

First of all, this is the new link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/intelligence/virus-initiative-criteria

The criteria have also changed and they are more complex.

Assuming you have a product build with a 3rd party SDK, here are the requirements to become a member:

1. Offer an antimalware or antivirus product that is one of the following:

   - Your organization's own creation.
   - Developed by using an SDK (engine and other components) from another MVI Partner company and your organization adds a custom UI and/or other functionality.
2. Have your own malware research team unless you build a product based on an SDK.
3. **Be active and have a positive reputation in the antimalware industry.**
   Activity can include participation in industry conferences or being reviewed in an industry standard report such as AV Comparatives, OPSWAT or Gartner.
4. Be willing to sign a non-disclosure agreement (NDA) with Microsoft.
5. Be willing to sign a program license agreement.
6. **Be willing to adhere to program requirements for antimalware apps. These requirements define the behavior of antimalware apps necessary to ensure proper interaction with Windows.**
7. **Submit your app to Microsoft for periodic performance testing.**
8. **Certified through independent testing by at least one industry standard organization.**

The most hard to achieve requirements are marked bold.

If you want more details what these things require, check out my company's blog post [here](https://www.endpoint-cybersecurity.com/microsoft-virus-initiative-membership/).

Comment: It wasn't easy, but I found *official* docs about the protected process requirement (that implies ELAM signature requirement) in the "What's new" document of the corresponding Win10 version: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/whats-new/whats-new-windows-10-version-1809