# How to Register a software as an Antivirus for Windows 7?

Tags: windows, registry, wmi, antivirus

I know that we could use WMI to retrieve information about installed security apps and their statuses, if any, Like the answer in the link here [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1331887/detect-antivirus-on-windows-using-c-sharp). The question is: How to go the opposite road?

I mean, I'm trying to make my personal Antivirus software (I know, Big, Huge, Hard, Some will think I'm kidding, I'm OK with all that). I want to know how to register me software as an Antivirus for windows 7? I'm using C# BTW.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I tell the "windows security center" that I'm an "antivirus"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3698285/how-can-i-tell-the-windows-security-center-that-im-an-antivirus)

Comment: How will you write the file system filter in C#?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the registry, by adding a key into the SecurityCenter I guess.

On Windows XP it is called SecurityCenter
On Windows Vista, 7, 8 it is called SecurityCenter2